# Use from multiple sessions of iSCSI

Tags: storage, iscsi

I have set the configuration file of iSCSI to attempt login at startup.
The system creates two session with two different targets.

How can I format and mount a particular node using the existing session.

The `iscsiadm -m node` returns nothing, probably because the client already has a session with target.

update: Even after logging out the discovery returns the targets but the node mode does not work.